# .htaccess Redirect user when accessing directory uploads

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect to the home page example (mysite.com) every time any user accesses any file or the uploads own directory that uploads directory has subdir year> month inside has image files I wanted the user to be redirected to the site home page without external images being broken
can anybody help me?
any help is welcome.
[image]

my actual .htacess file

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)fbclid=

RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=permanent]

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value engine off
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.((php[0-9]?)|p?html?|pl|sh|java|cpp|c|h|js|rc)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: You need to implement an external redirection for a pattern matching the requests you describe.

Comment: thanks for your reply. how could I do that. I'm a layman

Comment: This is not rocket science. You will find thousands of examples alone here on StackOverflow. ANd I really recomment that you start reading the documentation of the tool you use: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  As typical for OpenSource it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.

Comment: Sorry, I just realize that you add a condition in your last sentence: "without external images being broken" ... What do you actually mean by that? What are "external images"?

Comment: @arkascha example when another site adds the image to its page src = "img.jpg" it gets broken I referred to it when I said "without the images getting broken on external links"

Comment: You cannot reliably tell apart "other sites"  and your own site. You publish those images. That means you publish them. You'd have to setup separate paths to access such images then. That way you can apply separate controlling rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ;)
For jpg,png,gif redirect

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite,com/ .*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite,com/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://mysite,com/  [NC,R,L] // PAGE TO REDIRECT




<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value engine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value engine off
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.((php[0-9]?)|p?html?|pl|sh|java|cpp|c|h|js|rc)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: img is broken on external :(

Comment: The pattern `^.*\.*$` does not really make sense... but even if - how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Davi try again